# DateTime Parse Exact. Not working on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

```
var time = "21/12/2017 12:30:00 p.m.";
DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

This code seems to work finally locally but not on Azure.

Comment: `p.m.` is unusual. I'm surprised that works at all. Perhaps this relates to the _culture_ of the thread?

Comment: Check this out, it needs culture, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519070/datetime-tryparse-failing-in-azure-web-app

Comment: Ghaleb. Already set in web.config.

Comment: Jacob. Code has been running on Azure for couple years... But only stopped working today. Doesn't appear to be any changes to code that would have effected this.

Comment: Take a look at this https://azureinmycloud.net/2011/10/26/working-with-datetime-now-in-windows-azure-apps/

Comment: What is your local culture?

Comment: I worry any time I see a `Parse*` / `ToString` that doesn't specify an explicit culture.... 99% of the time: specifying the culture fixes it; the notion of "current culture" is comparable to the notion of `Encoding.Default`: *never use it* (expect for stuff that doesn't matter, like a debug log)

Comment: I agree with @Jacob though; `p.m.` is *highly* irregular; `pm`: sure, but with the periods? not so much

Comment: @MarcGravell `p.m.` is valid in a few cultures, for example `mi-NZ` (and OP appears to be in New Zealand)

Comment: @DavidG indeed, I ran a test locally - it is [valid in 51 cultures](https://gist.github.com/mgravell/5a4c0df62aaff65fb8b50b6abec2e97d); the key thing is to specify one in which it is valid

Comment: @MarcGravell Same here, but only 49 for me :)

Comment: @DavidG different OS versions and locales, no doubt; I've added my code in  a gist in the comment edit

Comment: @MarcGravell Interesting, I actually did it the other way round, just counting all cultures that produce `p.m.`, your code gives 51 for me too so there's a couple in there that don't default to `p.m.` but will parse successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is almost certainly failing when trying to parse the AM/PM designator. Depending on the culture, PM could be `PM`, `p.m.`, `a.k` or even `popodne`. You just need to specify the culture when parsing:

```
var time = "21/12/2017 12:30:00 p.m.";
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("mi-NZ");
DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", culture);
```

Comment: This infact does work. However the CultureInfo should really be "en-NZ" when I do this it fails.

 var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-NZ");

Comment: What is the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` when you run locally? Where do the date strings come from, that's the culure you need to use.

Comment: Locally it is en-NZ

Comment: Which means the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator` should be `PM` and the code you have just can't work.

Comment: OKay thanks.  Just weird that the code just stopped working after being in production for a number of years. Was trying to figure out why, I presume something changed on Azure, but I don't understand what.  Thanks for your time.